# AWS LAMBDA - Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'asn1' from 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust' (unknown location)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

How to fix the issue in AWS LAMBDA  - Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'asn1' from 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust' (unknown location)

Comment: This looks like a copy and paste of a stacktrace, it needs an actual question and some expected behavior descriptions

Comment: This error looks like, that are some dependencies missing. If you are using a library, which is not available by default for AWS Lambda, than this will throw an error like this. Eighter you add in your function the library (be aware of using same Python version, same operating system (Linux -> or WSL on Windows) and same architecture (especially for cryptographic libraries) and add this to your zip file. Or read more about Layers, if you have more than one function, using this library.